# Web3 getTransaction returns null

Tags: javascript, web3js, ethers.js

I'm encountering a problem with [web3.eth.getTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#gettransaction).

When using this function on local blockchain, given the transaction hash i just made, the function returns a proper object. But when i try to use the same set up for mainnet network, the getTransaction always returns null.

1. I can take the hash i pass to the getTransaction and find the tx on etherscan while function returns null.
2. On local blockchain everything works, mainnet always returns null
3. I'm using web ver: "^1.0.0-beta.37"
4. I'm also using the web3 library for different things in the code, and they work, both mainnet and local. So it's only getTransaction that behaves weird.

How my function looks like:

```
const advancedValidation = async hash => {
    const tx = await web3Proxy.web3.eth.getTransaction(hash);
    console.log(tx) // Will always be null
    if (!tx) return null;
    ...
}
```

Comment: what is your provider? `infura`, `your own node` or `metamask`?

Answer (score 1):

So current function will return null if your given transaction hash is not in Mainnet chain. Pleases one more time check the provided hash via [Etherescan](https://etherscan.io/), of course, if you are connected to the Ethereum chain.

Comment: I forgot to mention most important thing which is that i want to get tx that is currently pending...

From what i found the getTransaction can only return me tx that was already mined? And on my own node its instant that's why it works there?